# PhpStorm - change the path to images - how to update all paths with a batch process

Tags: html, phpstorm, batch-processing

I want to change the path to images I have on my site however there are hundreds to change.

Is there a batch process for this?

Comment: where are the images at present (e.g. web, assets) and where are you trying to change them to?

Comment: They are in a folder called img but I want to change the name of the folder and update all instances that are linked to that folder. But there are 100's of instances within my code

Comment: The most obvious `Edit | Find | Replace in Path...` ? You may also try renaming folder .. and IDE may rename all references (never used myself this one so not 100% sure).

Comment: AHHH YES @LazyOne the classic that I overlooked... just replaced 483 instances in one hit.... Lovely. You should post this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the most obvious approach: global find & replace.

`Edit | Find | Replace in Path...` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd> using Default keymap).

Search functionality allows you to specify the very narrow search scope -- only specific folder .. or user-defined custom scope where you can include on per-file level.

If find finds too many possible occurrences (search is too broad -- e.g. folder name is not too unique etc) you can still review and exclude particular occurrences before doing actual replace part.